# WebDav (AnchorClick, open as folder) does not work anymore in IE9

Tags: internet-explorer, webdav, internet-explorer-9

We use the following piece of HTML to open a WebDav folder view. This has stopped working with IE9 if Internet Explorer is runnig in browser mode IE9 and document mode IE9.
When switching document mode back to IE8 compatibility it works. However, we don't want that, as we would like to take advantage of IE9's new scripting improvements.

The effect is that under IE9 the browser does not ask for the user's login information, **instead it does a standard HTTP GET, not using the WebDav mini redirector**.

Note that editing documents via WebDav using ActiveX still works fine, just the folder view is affected.

Can somebody tell me if the code can be adjusted to make it work again in IE9? Or is it a bug in IE9?

```
<a href="https://webdav.myserver.com/" folder="https://webdav.myserver.com/" style="behavior: url(#default#AnchorClick);" target="_blank">WebDAV link (#AnchorClick, href)</a>
```

We also tried "`behavior: url(#default#httpFolder)`" as an alternative and "`style="-ms-behavior: url(#default#AnchorClick);`" - same issue.

It also does not make a difference to use http:// instead of https://.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Found a way that works also with IE9. It's from Microsoft's documentation about "httpFolder".

```
<HTML>
  <HEAD>

<SCRIPT>
    function fnDavStart(oSpanObj, sPath) {
        oSpanObj.navigateFrame(sPath, "_blank");
    }
</SCRIPT>
</HEAD>

<body>
<div ID=davDiv>
<SPAN ID=oWebDavHelper style="behavior:url('#default#httpFolder');" onclick = "fnDavStart(this, 'https://webdav.myserver.com')">
PLACEHOLDER
</SPAN>
</div>

</body>
```